# MouseOver style trigger won't change background

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-style

New to WPF, coming from a web background.

My style trigger won't change button background. Style XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="GhostWhite" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F48230"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Button XAML (nothing relevant in Window or Grid attributes):

```
<Window...>
    <Grid...>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Name="btnEdit" Cursor="Hand" Content="Edit Settings..." HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Margin="0,0,5,0" Click="btnEdit_Click"/>
            <Button Name="btnExit" Cursor="Hand" Content="Exit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Margin="5,0,0,0" Click="btnExit_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The buttons do pick up the background style in the resources section, but not the trigger - mouseover results in default behaviour.

Supplementary question: Is there a way I can debug this? I looked in Live Visual Tree but couldn't figure out how to get the info I need.

Comment: I guess the visual states in the button style takes presedence over the triggers. You probably need to restyle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF Controls have a *Template* property of type *ControlTemplate*. This property tells WPF how to draw the control on the screen. A WPF Button uses Windows Chrome in it's *ControlTemplate* which uses user selected system colors to allow for consistency between different applications. Leveraging the magic of WPF and XAML, you can create your own *ControlTemplate* to make the button look any way you see fit.

Create a style with a key so you can choose which buttons use the template:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="GhostWhite" />
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <!-- a simple square button -->
                    <Border Name="wrapper"
                            Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                            Background="#01000000">
                        <!-- notice the wrapper has a background that is NEAR transparent. This is important. It'll ensure the button raises the click event -->
                        <Border Name=inner
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
       <Style.Triggers>
           <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFF48230"/>
           </Trigger>
           <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF99501B"/>
           </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

And then to use the template on a button:

```
<Window...>
    <Grid...>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" Name="btnEdit" Cursor="Hand" Content="Edit Settings..." HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Margin="0,0,5,0" Click="btnEdit_Click"/>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" Name="btnExit" Cursor="Hand" Content="Exit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Margin="5,0,0,0" Click="btnExit_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works and looks like a better way of doing it, so I've accepted it. Any idea why mine wasn't working, though?

Comment: Because the ControlTemplate that buttons use by default are styled with windows chrome. The colors are bound to system colors.